# In this program how this line work "flag[str[i]-'a']++;" can anyone explain?

Tags: c, arrays

I have doubt in this line `flag[str[i]-'a']++;` how this line work.
For full program visit http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-anagram-program

```
char str[44];  
int flag[26],i=0;
gets(str);  
while(str[i]!='\0')
{
   flag[str[i]-'a']++; // How this line work
   i++;
}
i=0;
while(str[i]!='\0')
{
   printf("\n%d, %d ",str[i]-'a');
   i++;                        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lowercase 'a' resolves to decimal 97.  Subtracting 97 basically allows you to use characters 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. as indexes to the `flag` array.  Once you have that, the `++` is incrementing the appropriate letter slot in the array.

So `flag[0]` is for the letter 'a', `flag[1]` is for the letter 'b', and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
flag[str[i]-'a']++;
```

post incrementing flag[someindex] value

someindex vale is counted str[i]-'a'

```
if str[i]='c' then   
someindex='c'-'a'   ==> someindex=2
```

post incrementing flag[2];

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing you have a lower case letter in `str[i]` and in that case `str[i]-'a'` will mean the letter's number, as in

```
a=0
b=1
c=2
.
.
.
```

and at the end you have

```
flag[str[i]-'a']++;
```

so it's an array of letters, incrementing each iteration the current letter's cell and generally **it counts how many times each letter appears**

for example if you have the string "aaccdvb

you'll get:

```
str[0] = 2
str[1] = 1
str[2] = 2
str[3] = 1
str[21] = 1
```

and all the rest are 0

Answer (score 0):

Without really parsing the rest of the program... `flag[str[i]-'a']++` translates to:

- Take a value `str[i]` and subtract it from `'a'`.  `'a'` resolves to 97 in ASCII, so you're taking whatever value is in `str[i]` and subtracting it from 97.
- Take the result of the difference and use it as an index into the `flag` array.
- Apply a post-increment operation of the resulting value determined by the previous two steps.

Comment: Thanks friend, Now i can understand the code.